# Update a piece of text to the last time Google Doc was update

Tags: google-docs

I was wondering, is there a way to update a piece of text on the first page with the date and time of the last time the doc was edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no, there isn't. Google Docs only has one event: Open.

**References**
[Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script- Google editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)
[Event Objects > Google Docs Events - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_docs_events)